# App freezes when calling overridePendingTransiton

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to apply right-to-left animation when a new activity starts, but my app is freezing completely whenever I click the TextView that starts the activity,

here are my animation files:

enter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

exit :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

here is my MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @BindView(R.id.input_email) EditText email;
    @BindView(R.id.input_password) EditText password;
    @BindView(R.id.login_button) AppCompatButton loginButton;
    @BindView(R.id.signup_link_user) TextView signUp

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);

            }
        });

     }

}
```

event log when TextView is clicked:

```
05-24 04:14:41.800 1206-1230/? E/WindowManager: Unhandled exception while laying out windows
          android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050012
              at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1359)
              at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2789)
              at android.content.res.Resources.getAnimation(Resources.java:1197)
              at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:75)
              at com.android.server.wm.AppTransition.loadAnimationRes(AppTransition.java:449)
              at com.android.server.wm.AppTransition.loadAnimation(AppTransition.java:1014)
              at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.applyAnimationLocked(WindowManagerService.java:3611)
              at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.setTokenVisibilityLocked(WindowManagerService.java:4733)
              at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.handleAppTransitionReadyLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9762)
              at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner(WindowManagerService.java:10508)
              at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedLoop(WindowManagerService.java:9310)
              at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9257)
              at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.access$400(WindowManagerService.java:201)
              at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:8117)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
              at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

I haven't changed anything in my styles.xml

Comment: Add the log please

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Did you get solution?@OdaiMohammed

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that you put animation files and integer.xml file in a value folder accessible to the Android version you are testing.

I made the mistake of having an integer.xml file only in a values-v29 folder, so the project compiled and ran, but the integer was not available for lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try, clearing app data and running again. No need to uninstall.